# MySQL - Conditional query results based on polymorphic table values?

Tags: mysql, sql, polymorphism

I have a polymorphic table `creationables` and can't figure out a key part for a conditional query that returns all `creationables` based on the`creationable_type` field value (`human` or `robot`), based on whether or not they were deleted from their respective tables (`humans`, `robots`, and a `robots` and `robot_upgrades` combo). Here are the 4 tables followed by the pseudo query:

**1. creationables**

```
| id | creationable_type | creationable_id | robot_upgrade_id | is_activated
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |      human        |       1         |         0        |      1
| 2  |      robot        |       1         |         0        |      1
| 3  |      robot        |       2         |         1        |      1
```

**2. humans**

```
| id | name | deleted
---------------------
| 1  | Adam |  NULL
```

**3. robots**

```
| id |  name   | deleted
------------------------
| 1  | Droid X |  NULL
| 2  | Droid Y |  NULL
```

**4. robot_upgrades**

```
| id |  upgrade_name   | deleted
--------------------------------
| 1  |    Patch V4     |  NOW()
```

Pseudo query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM creationables

 // If creationable_type == 'human'
 // we want to get non deleted humans
    JOIN humans ON humans.id=creationable_id WHERE humans.deleted=NULL

 // If creationable_type == 'robot' and robot_upgrade_id == '0'
 // we want to get non deleted robots
    JOIN robots ON robots.id=creationable_id WHERE robots.deleted=NULL

 // If creationable_type == 'robot' and robot_upgrade_id != '0'
 // we want to check both robots and robot_upgrades tables
 // and if either of them was deleted we do not want to return them
 // we want to get non deleted robots/robot_upgrades combo
    JOIN robots ON robots.id=creationable_id WHERE robots.deleted=NULL
    JOIN robot_upgrades ON robot_upgrades.id=robot_upgrade_id WHERE robot_upgrades.deleted=NULL

WHERE creationables.is_activated = '1'
```

Any idea what the correct conditional query would be based on the comments in the pseudo query?

**UPDATE**
Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bff9a6c/1)

Expected result should look like this:

```
| id | creationable_type | creationable_id | robot_upgrade_id | is_activated
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |      human        |       1         |         0        |      1
| 2  |      robot        |       1         |         0        |      1
```

`creationables` row with id 3 should not be returned since even though its robot is not deleted from `robots`, its related `robot_upgrade_id` 1 is deleted in `robot_upgrades`.

Comment: See any basic introductory book or tutorial on sql syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no direct way of doing it. INNER JOINS will exclude the preceding types right after the first JOIN, so you can use LEFT JOINS to do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM creationables A
    LEFT JOIN humans ON humans.id= A.creationable_id AND A.creationable_type = 'human' AND humans.deleted is NULL
    LEFT JOIN robots ON robots.id= A.creationable_id AND A.creationable_type = 'robot' AND robots.deleted is NULL
    LEFT JOIN robot_upgrades ON robot_upgrades.id=A.robot_upgrade_id AND A.creationable_type = 'robot' and robot_upgrade_id != '0' AND robot_upgrades.deleted is NULL
WHERE creationables.is_activated = '1';
```

OR you can try the UNION approach like this:

```
SELECT * FROM creationables A JOIN humans ON humans.id= A.creationable_id AND A.creationable_type = 'human' AND humans.deleted is NULL
  UNION
SELECT * FROM creationables A JOIN robots ON robots.id= A.creationable_id AND A.creationable_type = 'robot' AND robots.deleted is NULL
  UNION
SELECT * FROM creationables A JOIN robot_upgrades ON robot_upgrades.id=A.robot_upgrade_id AND A.creationable_type = 'robot' and robot_upgrade_id != '0' AND robot_upgrades.deleted is NULL
WHERE creationables.is_activated = '1';
```

If the robot update is deleted it should not return the robot either then you can use this query instead:

```
SELECT A.creationable_type, humans.name, null as "update" 
FROM creationables A 
JOIN humans ON humans.id= A.creationable_id AND A.creationable_type = 'human' AND humans.deleted is NULL
  UNION
SELECT A.creationable_type, robots.name, robot_upgrades.upgrade_name as "update"
FROM creationables A 
JOIN robots ON robots.id= A.creationable_id AND A.creationable_type = 'robot' AND robots.deleted is NULL
LEFT JOIN robot_upgrades ON robot_upgrades.id=A.robot_upgrade_id AND A.creationable_type = 'robot' and robot_upgrade_id != '0' AND robot_upgrades.deleted is NULL
WHERE A.is_activated = '1' AND robots.id NOT IN
(SELECT DISTINCT A.creationable_id FROM creationables A
JOIN robot_upgrades ON robot_upgrades.id=A.robot_upgrade_id AND A.creationable_type = 'robot' and robot_upgrade_id != '0' AND robot_upgrades.deleted is NOT NULL);
```

These might not be the best approaches but will get the work done, Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for jumping in umair, first issue was the WHERE clause creationables.is_activated = '1' should be A.is_activated since it's the alias assigned, otherwise it returns an error. But still after fixing that the returned results are not accurate. I tried both queries :)

Comment: The UNION Query works if your table robot_upgrades does not have value in deleted column. you have a check in place for third query the robot_upgrades.deleted is NULL, but in the database in SQL Fiddle the column has a value.

Comment: Same is the case for Droid X in the robots table.

Comment: Yes, they weren't null to test. Here's an updated fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bff9a6c/1), same as the original question, except the `robot_upgrades` id 1 is deleted. Because it is deleted, it should not return the Droid Y as a result, since id 3 in `creationables` is Droid Y WITH robot_upgrade_id 1 (where the upgrade was deleted, so that whole row should not be returned. So if a robot_upgrade_id is not 0, it means it exists in the robot_upgrades table, and even if the actual robot is not deleted, it should still not be returned since its upgrade was deleted, like in `creationables` row 3)

Comment: Added an update explaining the issue with the updated fiddle.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't clear to the requirements that the update being deleted also removes the robot in completely. I have updated the answer and added another query more aligned to your requirement.

Comment: Thank you for giving it another shot, but the results of the latest query does not match the expected results in the original question update we're after.

Comment: I have updated the query to include the ones that do not have updates now.

Comment: Thank you umair, this seems to work. I may open another question if there is a way to improve this query but looks like it pulls in the required fields. Very much appreciate your help with this polymorphic query!